# Sitefinity: Get page list of Awaiting Approval pages (Workflow)

Tags: api, sitefinity

We are using sitefinity 7.3

For pages we have activated one level workflow. How do I get the list of pages with status "Awaiting Approval" through API?

We want to get the list currently awaiting approval for being published.

Best Regards
Hardeep

Answer (score 0):

I believe its something like this:

```
var pagesAwaiting = PageManager.GetManager().GetPageNodes().Where(pn => pn.ApprovalWorkflowState == "Awaiting Approval");
```